# Change backgroundColor BEHIND keyboard with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

This sounds needless and crazy, but it's actually much more sane than it sounds.

I've been trying to find a way to do this and am pretty close to giving up. Currently I assume it's not possible.

What I'd like to do is change the color behind the keyboard so that the app doesn't have a big white area in the app switcher.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible - but fortunately on Android 11 and up the OS automatically closes the keyboard before switching apps, which makes a non-issue in the near-future.